# How to pass variable from java to jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

**EmployeeController.java**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.setFirstname(request.getParameter("firstName"));
            employee.setLastname(request.getParameter("lastName"));
            employee.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
            employee.setStatus(request.getParameter("status"));

            String employeeId = request.getParameter("email");

                employee.setEmail(employeeId);
                dao.addEmployee(employee);              

            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(employee_listing);
            request.setAttribute("employees", dao.getAllEmployees());
            view.forward(request, response);            
        }
```

**EmployeeDao.java**

```
HttpServletRequest request;   

   public void addEmployee(Employee employee) throws ServletException, IOException{
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("insert into login(firstname, lastname, email, pass, role, status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, 'employee', ?)");                               
            preparedStatement.setString(1, employee.getFirstname());            
            preparedStatement.setString(2, employee.getLastname());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, employee.getEmail());
            //preparedStatement.setString(4, employee.getFirstname());
            preparedStatement.setInt(4, employee.getFirstname().hashCode());
            preparedStatement.setString(5, employee.getStatus());
            //preparedStatement.setBoolean(4, employee.getStatus());
            int i = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            if(i > 0){
                System.out.println("Employee added successfully.");
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("successMessage", "Employee added successfully.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(e);
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**addEmployee.jsp**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="EmployeeController" name="frmAddEmployee" id="frmAddEmployee">
                                <!-- <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="adduser.jsp" name="frmAddEmployee" id="frmAddEmployee"> -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">First Name</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                          <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" id="firstName">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Last Name</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                          <input type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control" id="lastName" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Email</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Employee Status</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <label class="switch">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="1" checked>
                                                <div class="slider round"></div>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"> &nbsp; <!-- <button name="cancel"  onclick='employee-listing.jsp' class="btn btn-primary" >Cancel</button> -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

So basically when submit the form It redirects to EmployeeController.java file and get all the values in Employee and then redirect to EmployeeDao.java file to addEmployee(employee);

And I will get this in jsp page like ::

```
session.getAttribute("successMessage");
```

I tried all this but i didn't get any message form "successMessage" attribute and got only "null" value.

I also tried to `response.sendRedirect("employee-success.jsp")` but still it didnt redirect to that page.

So can anyone help me to set the value in java code and get that value in jsp page for further use.

Comment: `HttpSession session = null;` I don't understand how that attribute will be set into session with this code?

Comment: I guess `status` was always 0 because you didn't receive a NullPointerException

Comment: Could you add `session.setAttribute("successMessage", "Oups.");` into the catch part, next to the System.out.println ;)

Comment: @AxelH I think first he needs to create `HttpSession` object.

Comment: HttpServletRequest request;

HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("successMessage", "Employee added successfully.");

I tried this but its not working.

Comment: @VPK, indeed, I thought it came from the parameter ... well it should not even be in the DAO after all... throw an exception, return a boolean or anything an work with that into the servlet

Comment: @Hiten, you can get the `HttpSession` from your `request` like `request.getSession` which will return the `HttpSession` object and then pass it to your Dao method. Then set the attributes to that session object.

Comment: @VPK I already did it but i just recived only null.

Comment: @Hiten you need to access `request` object to `addEmployee`  method , then get `session` object from it

Comment: Could you update the code so that we can see what is going wrong?

Comment: @VPK I update the code .Please check it.

Comment: hv you execute this code

Comment: why `HttpServletRequest request; ` is declared outside of the `addEmployee` method? You have to pass the request object to the `addEmployee` method.

Comment: @VPK I globally declared it.
Otherwise I have to initialize with null value in addEmployee() function.
And I also got the  **java.lang.NullPointerException** exception.

Comment: you may get `NullPointerException`

Comment: Are you calling `addEmployee` method from any servlet method? Off course you will get the NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your

```
public void addEmployee(Employee employee)
```

to

```
public void addEmployee(Employee employee, HttpServletRequest request)
```

pass `HttpServletRequest` object in `EmployeeController.java`

```
dao.addEmployee(employee,request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the request object from your Controller,

```
dao.addEmployee(employee);
```

and access the sessionAttribute directly in your jsp anywhere like,

```
${successMessage}
```

**OR**

you can send the success message back to your Controller from `addEmployee` method and then set that String message in request attribute like,

```
String successMessage = dao.addEmployee(employee);              

RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(employee_listing);
request.setAttribute("employees", dao.getAllEmployees());
request.setAttribute("successMessage", successMessage);
```

In your DAO method,

```
public String addEmployee(Employee employee) throws ServletException, IOException{
    String successMessage = "";
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("insert into login(firstname, lastname, email, pass, role, status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, 'employee', ?)");                               
        preparedStatement.setString(1, employee.getFirstname());            
        preparedStatement.setString(2, employee.getLastname());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, employee.getEmail());
        //preparedStatement.setString(4, employee.getFirstname());
        preparedStatement.setInt(4, employee.getFirstname().hashCode());
        preparedStatement.setString(5, employee.getStatus());
        //preparedStatement.setBoolean(4, employee.getStatus());
        int i = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        if(i > 0){
            System.out.println("Employee added successfully.");
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            successMessage = "Employee added successfully.";
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e);
        //e.printStackTrace();
        successMessage = "Error occured while adding employee."
    }
    return successMessage;
}
```